# How do i fix the undefined issue that is logged in console for a articular date

Tags: javascript

```
  async function getjsondata() {
     try {
        state = await fetch('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json');
        data = await state.json();
     } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
  }
  
  var sumy = 0;
  var tt_list = [];
  async function getmonthnewcases() {
     
     await getmonthsum();
     await getjsondata();
     await getCountry();
     
     try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
           for (let z = listy[i]; z <= listy[i + 1]; z++) {
              for (key in data[isocount]["data"][z]) {
                 if (data[isocount]["data"][z].hasOwnProperty(key) == true) {
                    sumy += Number(data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"]);
                    tt_list[i] = sumy;
                 } else if (typeof data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"] === "undefined") {
                    data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"] = sumy;
                    continue;
                 }
                 if (z == data[isocount]["data"].length - 1) {
                    break;
                 }
                 console.log(data[isocount]["data"][z]["date"], sumy, data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"]);
              }
           }
        }
        console.log(tt_list);
     } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
     
  }
```

So this is how the code looks like am having trouble solving the issue of undefined in a particular month date from the api call, i have tried so many other options but nothing seems to be working please i nned some help

Comment: I guess you mea here: `console.log(data[isocount]["data"][z]["date"], ...)`. Where is the sample data? Simplify the code with `let arr = data[isocount]["data"]` and iterate over `arr[z]`. Where is *listy* defined?

Answer (score 0):

First is seems that you have some errors in the code,
You are not returning anything from `getjsondata`.
And you are not using the results in `getmonthnewcases`

(See code comments)

```
async function getjsondata() {
 try {
    state = await fetch('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json');
    return await state.json(); //<-- here
 } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
 }
}

var sumy = 0;
var tt_list = [];
async function getmonthnewcases() {
 
 await getmonthsum();
 const data = await getjsondata(); //<-- and here
 await getCountry();
 
 try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       for (let z = listy[i]; z <= listy[i + 1]; z++) {
          for (key in data[isocount]["data"][z]) {
             if (data[isocount]["data"][z].hasOwnProperty(key) == true) {
                sumy += Number(data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"]);
                tt_list[i] = sumy;
             } else if (typeof data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"] === "undefined") {
                data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"] = sumy;
                continue;
             }
             if (z == data[isocount]["data"].length - 1) {
                break;
             }
             console.log(data[isocount]["data"][z]["date"], sumy, data[isocount]["data"][z]["total_cases_per_million"]);
          }
       }
    }
    console.log(tt_list);
 } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
 }
```

}

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.